timer event, init and end of loop
I have a timer event that iterates from 1 to 6, this works fine.
The doubleclick event works, it sets the counter to 1, then in combination with the click event the timer starts.
What I want in addition is this:

I want to stop at the end, meaning 6, but not 0
Edit: I solved this by changing the default value of the lookup transform from 0 to this

"default":  {"signal": "length(data('indexAll'))"}


When I doubleclick in combination with the shiftkey I want the counter set to the end, meaning 6, e.g., when I stop the timer at 4

This is my code
{
    "data": [
    {
      "name": "data",
            "values": [{"Month": 1},{"Month": 2},{"Month": 3},{"Month": 4},{"Month": 5},{"Month": 6}]
        },
        {
            "name": "indexAll",
            "source": "data",
            "transform": [
                {   "type": "project",
                    "fields": ["Month"]
                },
                {   "type": "window",
                    "ops": ["row_number"],
                    "as": ["rowid"],
                    "sort": {"field": ["Month"], "order": ["ascending"]}
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "index",
            "source": "indexAll",
            "transform": [
                { "type": "formula", "as": "index", "expr": "counter" },
                {
                    "type": "lookup",
                    "from": "indexAll",
                    "key": "rowid",
                    "fields": ["index"],
                    "values": ["Month"],
                    "as": ["Month"],
                    "default":  {"signal": "length(data('indexAll'))"}
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "dataFiltered",
            "source": "data",
            "transform": [
                {
                    "type": "filter",
                    "expr": "datum['Month'] <= pluck(data('index') , 'Month')[0]"
                }
            ]
        }
  ],
    "signals": [
    {
            "name": "run",
            "value": false,
            "on": [{ "events": "click", "update": "!run" }]
        },
        {
            "name": "counter",
            "update": "length(data('indexAll'))",
            "on": [
                {
                    "events": { "type": "timer", "throttle": 1000},
                    "update": "run && counter <= length(data('indexAll')) ? counter + 1 : counter"
                },
                { "events": { "type": "dblclick" }, "update": "1"}
                //{ "events": { "type": "dblclick.shiftKey" }, "update": "length(data('indexAll'))"}
            ]
        }
  ],
    "scales": [
        { "name": "scaleY", "type": "band",
            "domain": {"data": "dataFiltered", "field": "Month"},
      "range": "height",
      "padding": 0.1,
      "round": true
        },
        { "name":   "scaleX", "type": "linear",
            "domain": {"data": "dataFiltered", "field": "Month"},
            "range": "width",
            "nice": true
        }
    ],
    "axes": [
        {"scale": "scaleY", "orient": "left"},
        {"scale": "scaleX", "orient": "bottom"}
    ],
  "marks": [
        {   "description": "the counter",
            "type": "text",
            "from": { "data": "index" },
            "encode": {
                "update": {
                    "text": {
                        "signal": "'Month: ' + datum['Month']"
                    },
                    "align": { "value": "left" },
                    "fill": { "value": "darkgray" },
                    "x": { "signal": "-30" },
                    "y": { "signal": " -50" },
                    "fontSize": { "value": 24 }
                }
            }
        },
        {   "description": "the bars",
            "type": "rect",
            "from": {"data": "dataFiltered"},
            "encode": {
                "update": {
                    "y": {"field": "Month", "scale": "scaleY"
                    },
                    "height": {"band": 1, "scale": "scaleY"},
                    "x": {"field": "Month", "scale": "scaleX"},
                    "x2": {"value": 0 }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
  
}


I have found the solution, it was necessary to filter the base doubleclick and the shiftKey+doubleclick
the spec now looks like this:
{
    "data": [
    {
      "name": "data",
            "values": [{"Month": 1},{"Month": 2},{"Month": 3},{"Month": 4},{"Month": 5},{"Month": 6}]
        },
        {
            "name": "indexAll",
            "source": "data",
            "transform": [
                {   "type": "project",
                    "fields": ["Month"]
                },
                {   "type": "window",
                    "ops": ["row_number"],
                    "as": ["rowid"],
                    "sort": {"field": ["Month"], "order": ["ascending"]}
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "index",
            "source": "indexAll",
            "transform": [
                { "type": "formula", "as": "index", "expr": "counter" },
                {
                    "type": "lookup",
                    "from": "indexAll",
                    "key": "rowid",
                    "fields": ["index"],
                    "values": ["Month"],
                    "as": ["Month"],
                    "default":  {"signal": "length(data('indexAll'))"}
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "dataFiltered",
            "source": "data",
            "transform": [
                {
                    "type": "filter",
                    "expr": "datum['Month'] <= pluck(data('index') , 'Month')[0]"
                }
            ]
        }
  ],
    "signals": [
    {
            "name": "run",
            "value": false,
            "on": [{ "events": "click", "update": "!run" }]
        },
        {
            "name": "counter",
            "react": true,
            "value": "length(data('indexAll'))",
            "update": "length(data('indexAll'))",
            "on": [
                {
                    "events": { "type": "timer", "throttle": 1000},
                    "update": "run && counter <= length(data('indexAll')) ? counter + 1 : counter"
                },
                
                /*
                { "events": { "type": "dblclick"}, "update": "length(data('indexAll'))"}
                */
                { "events": { "type": "dblclick", "filter": ["!event.shiftKey"]}, "update": "1"},
                { "events": { "type": "dblclick", "filter": ["event.shiftKey"]}, "update": "length(data('indexAll'))"}
                
            ]

            /*
            {
  "type": "mousedown",
  "marktype": "image",
  "filter": ["event.ctrlKey", "event.button === 0"]
}
            */
        }
  ],
    "scales": [
        { "name": "scaleY", "type": "band",
            "domain": {"data": "dataFiltered", "field": "Month"},
      "range": "height",
      "padding": 0.1,
      "round": true
        },
        { "name":   "scaleX", "type": "linear",
            "domain": {"data": "dataFiltered", "field": "Month"},
            "range": "width",
            "nice": true
        }
    ],
    "axes": [
        {"scale": "scaleY", "orient": "left"},
        {"scale": "scaleX", "orient": "bottom"}
    ],
  "marks": [
        {   "description": "the counter",
            "type": "text",
            "from": { "data": "index" },
            "encode": {
                "update": {
                    "text": {
                        "signal": "'Month: ' + datum['Month']"
                    },
                    "align": { "value": "left" },
                    "fill": { "value": "darkgray" },
                    "x": { "signal": "-30" },
                    "y": { "signal": " -50" },
                    "fontSize": { "value": 24 }
                }
            }
        },
        {   "description": "the bars",
            "type": "rect",
            "from": {"data": "dataFiltered"},
            "encode": {
                "update": {
                    "y": {"field": "Month", "scale": "scaleY"
                    },
                    "height": {"band": 1, "scale": "scaleY"},
                    "x": {"field": "Month", "scale": "scaleX"},
                    "x2": {"value": 0 }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
  
}

